# unicorn_rails: Command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I killed the master and worker processes using `kill -9 <processnumber>`. When trying to restart the server using the following command, I get the error `"unicorn_rails: Command not found."`

`unicorn_rails -p 3000 -E production -D`

Everything was working before killing the processes.

I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: I was able to run that command using unicorn's full path (i.e. /tool/pandora64/.package/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/unicorn_rails) but i'm now having a new problem. I'm getting this error: Proxy Error The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server. The proxy server could not handle the request POST /GET. Reason: Error reading from remote server any ideas?

Comment: first let us know, do you want to start master or production server

Answer (score 6):

Try `bundle exec unicorn_rails ...`. Chances are Unicorn is installed as a part of your bundle, and not in the global gem path.

Comment: I was able to run that command using unicorn's full path (i.e. /tool/pandora64/.package/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/unicorn_rails) but i'm now having a new problem. I'm getting this error: Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request POST /GET.

Reason: Error reading from remote server

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you also need to restart nginx/apache, or some other web server that is reverse proxying in front of unicorn?

Answer (score 0):

Try `cap development unicorn:start`

It will work for port 3000